# VHDL - Systolic Array: Single cells in an array of cells behave differently in simulation

Tags: arrays, vhdl, digital

I am currently trying to write a basic systolic array in VHDL to multiply 2 3x3 matrices, so AxB. I started with writing a single cell which computes result = a0 * b0 + a1 * b1 + a2 * b2. This one works well. The VHDL code of the single cell looks like this:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;


entity sys_cell is
    port 
    (   
        clk, reset : in std_ulogic; --active low
        a_in, b_in  : in    integer;
        a_out, b_out : out integer;
        
        result : out integer
    );
end sys_cell;


architecture sys_cell_behave of sys_cell is
                    
    signal counter : unsigned(3 downto 0) := "0000";
    signal sign_a_out, sign_b_out, sign_result : integer := 0;
begin

    result <= sign_result;

    counter_process : process (clk, reset)
    begin
        if (reset = '0') then
            counter <= "0000";
        elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
            counter <= counter + 1;
        else
            NULL;
        end if;
    end process counter_process;
    
    result_process : process (counter)
    begin
        case(counter) is
            when "0000" =>
                sign_result <= 0;
            when others =>
                sign_result <= sign_result + (a_in * b_in);
        end case;
    end process result_process;
    
    output_process : process (counter)
    begin
        case(counter) is
            when "0000" =>
                a_out <= 0;
                b_out <= 0;
            when "0001" =>
                sign_a_out <= a_in;
                sign_b_out <= b_in;
            when others =>
                a_out <= sign_a_out;
                b_out <= sign_b_out;
                sign_a_out <= a_in;
                sign_b_out <= b_in;
        end case;
    end process output_process;
    
end sys_cell_behave;
```

[Simulation of one cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5IFy.png)

As a next step, I put together 9 cells into one array. The code of the 3x3 array looks like this:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;


entity sys_array is
    port 
    (
        a0, a1, a2  :   in integer;
        b0, b1, b2  :   in integer;
        
        c00, c01, c02, c10, c11, c12, c20, c21, c22 :   out integer;
        
        reset, clk  :   in std_ulogic
    );
end sys_array;


architecture sys_array_behave of sys_array is
                    
    component sys_cell is
        port 
        (
            clk, reset : in std_ulogic; --active low
            a_in, b_in  : in    integer;
            a_out, b_out : out integer;
            
            result : out integer            
        );
    end component sys_cell;
    
    signal a_out_00, a_out_01, a_out_02, a_out_10, a_out_11, a_out_12, a_out_20, a_out_21, a_out_22 :   integer := 0;   
    signal b_out_00, b_out_01, b_out_02, b_out_10, b_out_11, b_out_12, b_out_20, b_out_21, b_out_22 :   integer := 0;
    
begin
    -- oben links
    sys_cell_00 : sys_cell
    port map
    (
        clk,
        reset,
        a0,
        b0,
        a_out_00,
        b_out_00,
        c00 
    );
    
    -- oben mitte
    sys_cell_01 : sys_cell
    port map
    (
        clk,
        reset,
        a_out_00,
        b1,
        a_out_01,
        b_out_01,
        c01
    );
    
    -- oben rechts
    sys_cell_02 : sys_cell
    port map
    (
        clk,
        reset,
        a_out_01,
        b2,
        open,
        b_out_02,
        c02
    );
    
    -- mitte links
    sys_cell_10 : sys_cell
    port map
    (
        clk,
        reset,
        a1,
        b_out_00,
        a_out_10,
        b_out_10,
        c10
    );
    
    -- mitte mitte
    sys_cell_11 : sys_cell
    port map
    (
        clk,
        reset,
        a_out_10,
        b_out_01,
        a_out_11,
        b_out_11,
        c11
    );
    
    -- mitte rechts
    sys_cell_12 : sys_cell
    port map
    (
        clk,
        reset,
        a_out_11,
        b_out_02,
        open,
        b_out_12,
        c12     
    );
    
    -- unten links
    sys_cell_20 : sys_cell
    port map
    (
        clk,
        reset,
        a2,
        b_out_10,
        a_out_20,
        open,
        c20
    );
    
    -- unten mitte
    sys_cell_21 : sys_cell
    port map
    (
        clk,
        reset,
        a_out_20,
        b_out_11,
        a_out_21,
        open,
        c21
    );
    
    -- unten rechts
    sys_cell_22 : sys_cell
    port map
    (
        clk,
        reset,
        a_out_21,
        b_out_12,
        open,
        open,
        c22
    );
            
    
end sys_array_behave;
```

The problem that occurs in the simulation that every cell's computation results are wrong, except for the very first one. I added a picture of the simulation. The red line separates the signals of sys_cell_00 and sys_cell_01. The blue arrows indicate the different behaviour of these two cells. Why does sys_cell_00 compute the result and sys_cell_01 does not? The only signal that differs is the counter value. But the vhdl code in "result_process" should make them behave identically.
[Simulation of the cell array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gm5Q4.png)

Comment: Your sys_cell component has many signals missing from sensitivity lists. Specifically,  `result_process` is missing `sign_result` `a_in` and `b_in` . Output_process is missing `a_in` `b_in` and sign_a/b_out. When this is fixed, you will have a logic loop on `sign_result` because it updates itself in an async process.

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten my code and it works now. As a basic start I have the following code now:

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;


entity sys_cell is
    port 
    (   
        clk, reset : in std_ulogic; --active low
        a_in, b_in  : in    integer;
        a_out, b_out : out integer;
        
        result : out integer
    );
end sys_cell;


architecture sys_cell_behave of sys_cell is
                    
    signal sign_result : integer := 0;

begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if(reset = '1') then
            if (rising_edge(clk)) then
                sign_result <= sign_result + a_in * b_in;
                a_out <= a_in;
                b_out <= b_in;
            else 
                NULL;
            end if;
        else
            a_out <= 0;
            b_out <= 0;
            result <= 0;
            sign_result <= 0;
        end if;
        result <= sign_result;
    end process;
    
end sys_cell_behave;
```

The code of the 3x3 Array has not changed

Comment: Some style points. 1. Your reset name is implied as active high,  yet you reset in non high state. Also,  usually,  reset is in the if branch when using if..else style. 2. Null choice with clock is pointless. 3. Result assignment should be inside the clock if branch.

Comment: Another style point about your top-level. You should have a look at `generate for` statements, they could be used to very elegantly instantiate your MxN cells.